# Why was Artemis 2.20.0 moved to Java 11 and is its JMS Client JAR compatible with Java 8 or be built with it?

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I'm running into incompatibility issues with other applications that are stuck on Java 8 that use the JMS Client JAR. Is there any way for this JAR to be compatible with Java 8?

Comment: Use the client from Artemis 2.19.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While ActiveMQ Artemis moved to Java 11 in version 2.20.0 you can still use older clients like the one from ActiveMQ Artemis 2.19.0 or even 2.19.1. Older clients are still compatible with newer versions of the broker.

To be clear, 2.19.x will stay on Java 8, but it will only be getting critical updates for a short time. It won't get any new features, etc.

Comment: I will use it! Thank you!